# jQuery UI Accordion - Click link and set active option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a link which when clicked the goes to the users messages.

I am trying to get it so that when the page loads after clicking the link the second tab is active.

```
$("#messages").click(function(){
    $("#user-menu").accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
});
```

I have found a similar question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681033/accordion-menu-active-state-after-link-click

But I was ideally looking for a more elegant solution.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, thank you.

Aaron

Comment: Could you, please, create a jsFiddle for your problem?